# Creating function with matrix argument

Tags: matrix, function-construction

I am completely new to programming, so I apologize in advance for a stupid question.

I want to program an algorithm for computing invariant factors of a finitely generated abelian group, so in essence I want to feed the algorithm a matrix of relations and get the reduced form of this matrix.

I have compiled a cumbersome code which makes the first step of the procedure, namely it takes a matrix and produces a matrix, in which the upper-left element divides all the elements in first row and in a first columm:

```
M = {{120, 51, 72, 33}, {30, 15, 18, 9}, {60, 30, 36, 18}};
If[FreeQ[M, 0], ## &[], Print [First[Dimensions[M]]]];
L = SparseArray[M]["NonzeroPositions"];
i = First[First[L]];
j = Part[First[L], 2];
M2 = M;
M2[[{1, i}]] = M2[[{i, 1}]];
M2[[All, {1, j}]] = M2[[All, {j, 1}]];
If[M2[[1, 1]] > 0, ## &[], 
  M2 = M2*Normal[
     SparseArray[{1 -> -1, i_ -> 1}, First[Dimensions[M2]]]]];
A = Table[0, {First[Dimensions[M2]] - 1}];

For[i = 2, i <= First[Dimensions[M2]], i++, 
  A[[i - 1]] = Boole[Divisible[M2[[i, 1]], M2[[1, 1]]]]];

While[A != Table[1, {First[Dimensions[M2]] - 1}], 
  For[i = 2, i <= First[Dimensions[M2]], i++,
   If[Divisible[M2[[i, 1]], M2[[1, 1]]], ## &[], 
    M3 = M2*Normal[
       SparseArray[{1 -> Quotient[M2[[i, 1]], M2[[1, 1]]]}, 
        First[Dimensions[M2]]]] ; M3[[{1, i}]] = M3[[{i, 1}]]; 
    M2 = M2 - M3; M2[[{1, i}]] = M2[[{i, 1}]]]]; 
  For[i = 2, i <= First[Dimensions[M2]], i++, 
   A[[i - 1]] = Boole[Divisible[M2[[i, 1]], M2[[1, 1]]]]]];
```

So on the matrix `M = {{120, 51, 72, 33}, {30, 15, 18, 9}, {60, 30, 36, 18}}` it gives `{{30, 15, 18, 9}, {120, 51, 72, 33}, {60, 30, 36, 18}}`.

Now I want to iterate this procedure, so I want to feed an arbitrary matrix into this code as a function. I got stuck on this problem for several hours, so I hope you could help me solve this.

Answer (score 4):

Put everything in a [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html) to localize your Symbols:

```
fn[m_?MatrixQ] :=
 Module[{M = m, L, i, j, M2, M3, A},
  If[FreeQ[M, 0], ## &[], Print[First[Dimensions[M]]]];
  L = SparseArray[M]["NonzeroPositions"];
  i = First[First[L]];
  j = Part[First[L], 2];
  M2 = M;
  M2[[{1, i}]] = M2[[{i, 1}]];
  M2[[All, {1, j}]] = M2[[All, {j, 1}]];
  If[M2[[1, 1]] > 0, ## &[], 
   M2 = M2*Normal[SparseArray[{1 -> -1, i_ -> 1}, First[Dimensions[M2]]]]];
  A = Table[0, {First[Dimensions[M2]] - 1}];
  For[i = 2, i <= First[Dimensions[M2]], i++, 
   A[[i - 1]] = Boole[Divisible[M2[[i, 1]], M2[[1, 1]]]]];
  While[A != Table[1, {First[Dimensions[M2]] - 1}], 
   For[i = 2, i <= First[Dimensions[M2]], i++, 
    If[Divisible[M2[[i, 1]], M2[[1, 1]]], ## &[], 
     M3 = M2*Normal[
        SparseArray[{1 -> Quotient[M2[[i, 1]], M2[[1, 1]]]}, First[Dimensions[M2]]]]; 
     M3[[{1, i}]] = M3[[{i, 1}]];
     M2 = M2 - M3; M2[[{1, i}]] = M2[[{i, 1}]]]];
   For[i = 2, i <= First[Dimensions[M2]], i++, 
    A[[i - 1]] = Boole[Divisible[M2[[i, 1]], M2[[1, 1]]]]]];
  {A, M2}
 ]
```

Now:

```
fn[
 {{120, 51, 72, 33}, {30, 15, 18, 9}, {60, 30, 36, 18}}
]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {{30, 15, 18, 9}, {120, 51, 72, 33}, {60, 30, 36, 18}}}
> ```

I didn't attempt to understand your operation; I assumed that you wanted both `A` and `M2` for output.

Answer (score 3):

A very crude way to do this would be:

```
func[mat_] := With[{M = mat},
  If[FreeQ[M, 0], ## &[], Print[First[Dimensions[M]]]];
  L = SparseArray[M]["NonzeroPositions"];
  i = First[First[L]];
  j = Part[First[L], 2];
  M2 = M;
  M2[[{1, i}]] = M2[[{i, 1}]];
  M2[[All, {1, j}]] = M2[[All, {j, 1}]];
  If[M2[[1, 1]] > 0, ## &[], 
   M2 = M2*Normal[
      SparseArray[{1 -> -1, i_ -> 1}, First[Dimensions[M2]]]]];
  A = Table[0, {First[Dimensions[M2]] - 1}];

  For[i = 2, i <= First[Dimensions[M2]], i++, 
   A[[i - 1]] = Boole[Divisible[M2[[i, 1]], M2[[1, 1]]]]];

  While[A != Table[1, {First[Dimensions[M2]] - 1}], 
   For[i = 2, i <= First[Dimensions[M2]], i++, 
    If[Divisible[M2[[i, 1]], M2[[1, 1]]], ## &[], 
     M3 = M2*Normal[
        SparseArray[{1 -> Quotient[M2[[i, 1]], M2[[1, 1]]]}, 
         First[Dimensions[M2]]]]; M3[[{1, i}]] = M3[[{i, 1}]];
     M2 = M2 - M3; M2[[{1, i}]] = M2[[{i, 1}]]]];
   For[i = 2, i <= First[Dimensions[M2]], i++, 
    A[[i - 1]] = Boole[Divisible[M2[[i, 1]], M2[[1, 1]]]]]];
  M2]
```

so that:

```
func[{{120, 51, 72, 33}, {30, 15, 18, 9}, {60, 30, 36, 18}}]
(*{{30, 15, 18, 9}, {120, 51, 72, 33}, {60, 30, 36, 18}} *)
```

There is no attempt here to localize the variables (which can be done within a [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html), for example) and you should consider reading the documentation and examples as you refactor your code.